# When optimizing inputs to minimize observed errors, why is it not more common to maximize one over the observed error?

Tags: optimization, calibration

Say I have a function that accepts inputs and hyper parameters to make a prediction, and I have a set of observed inputs and outputs to the true system. When I attempt to optimize the hyperparameters (using an approximate gradient descent approach) based on the root mean squared error (RMSE) between observations and predictions, I notice that the solution changes less rapidly when the error becomes small. From what I've read, it seems like a common solution to this problem is to optimize the log of the RMSE, to accentuate smaller values.

Why is it not more common to maximize the inverse of the RMSE, 1/RMSE, to stress the importance of small errors? If it is a common technique, what is it called?

Comment: Such transformations might help the user identify interesting points, but optimizing $RMSE$, $\log(RMSE)$, or $1/RMSE$ will result in the same solution (setting aside numerical issues that come with doing math on a computer). Is your question about some kind of gradient descent algorithm?

Comment: Hi Dave, yes it is. Thanks for pointing that out. I am using gradient approximations to perform gradient descent.